# Authentication issue on umbraco backend and internal user

Tags: authentication, umbraco

I'm currenntly designing an umbraco 9.5 based portal and i have now an authentication issue for backend users.

I have an reverse proxy in front of umbraco.

Frontend users always have to previously authenticate against an identity server, after successful authentication they receive an jwt token which is passed to umbraco. This runs well.

For backend users, when accessing the backend (/umbraco) i want to use the internal authentication in parallel to the jwt authentication.

On my dev environment this works quite well but on the centrally deployed environment i see the login dialog and always return to it after successful authentication.

The main difference between my local dev system and the centrally deployed system is that on my dev system reverse proxy and umbraco run both side by side as visual studio applications and are both reachable from the client-side (browser).

The centrally deployed system runs on a docker swarm stack, where only the reverse proxy endpoint is exposed to the world and it is the only endpoint, which is visible to the client side, umbraco itself is hosted as a docker container and is not directly reachable by the browser, only over the reverse proxy.

I am grateful for any advice on additional configuration, i possibly forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hosted umbraco as a replicated docker swarm service.
As outlined in umbraco documentation, backend is not designed to run in a replicated environment, this is the reason why authentication fails.